# IntelliJ Idea - search for a value in debugger

Tags: intellij-idea

I need to know if it is possible to search for a value in debugger in IntelliJ Idea.

Example: you have a huge object tree and you need to find string variable that is set to same particular value.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Expand this tree so that you see all those strings, and start typing what you search for. The speed search should do the rest. To get to the next/previous results press the down/up arrows respectively.

Comment: It can be buried really deep in structure so expanding only single tree may be not enough.

Comment: indeed. is there any way to know field by providing its value as an input?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to disappoint you, I don't think that this option exists.
The quick search will only look for values in expanded objects.

You can use some other tool to create a memory dump of this object, and look for your data there.

Answer (score 1):

In the "Find action ..." menu, you select "Fully expand tree node" or use Numpad *

Comment: In PyCharm, press numpad * multiple times to recursively expand child nodes. Or press `Alt-S` to enable the deviously hidden `Search inside collapsed nodes` option