# IDEA Debugger - Search variable in Variables

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I debug my project and have a list of `Variables`. This is enough big project and my question sounds :

There is any option to find for example variable named `objectColor` in this `Variables` list ?

Comment: Focus the Variables panel and start typing "obje..." - this will highlight all variables containing this string. You can use the arrow keys to navigate between those selections. BTW - this works in all lists and trees in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259254/intellij-idea-search-for-a-value-in-debugger